# Google Calendar API using Zend Library

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm following the tutorial on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/ for working with the Google Calendar API, but I'm running into some strange problems.  My PHP code looks like this

```
    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

    //create authenticated HTTP client for Calendar service
    $gcal = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $user = "daniel.lieberman610@gmail.com";
    $pass = "*******";
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $gcal);
    $gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);


    //generate query to get event list
    $query = $gcal->newEventQuery();
    $query->setUser($user);
    $query->setVisibility('private');
    $query->setProjection('basic');

    //get and parse calendar feed
    //print output

    try {
        $feed = $gcal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
        echo "<!--comment-->\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<!--different comment-->\n";
    }
```

Some kind of exception is occurring inside the try block, but not the `Zend_Gdata_App_Exception` because the error message is not being displayed.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Also, I am learning PHP as I go along here.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does `catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e);
    }` display?

Comment: @Liyali Nothing. Also, I put in some debugging code, and neither of the above comments that are in the try/catch blocks appear in the page source.

Comment: Maybe your code isn't executed because it fails before reaching the `try catch`? Or it could fail inside the try but without any exception thrown (but a PHP fatal error instead for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Move the try code to the beginning of the file. Is there an error shown? Here you will find a working example which I'm using in my Joomla extension https://github.com/Digital-Peak/GCalendar/blob/master/com_gcalendar/admin/libraries/GCalendar/GCalendarZendHelper.php

By the way I suggest to move to the new google calendar API v3 because they shut down version 2 (which uses Zend) probably next year. Here is the link to the libs https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads